# RxJs Distict utill changed, Check Deep objects?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a usecase which needs to avoid computation if subscption emits same object.

```
this.stateObject$
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged((obj1, obj2) => JSON.stringify({ obj: obj1 }) === JSON.stringify({ obj: obj2 })))
.subscribe(obj => heavyComputeTask(obj))
```

This will obviously not work if order of keys change and is inefficient as well.

> How can I write it in efficient way ?

Also, to avoid code repetition I wanted to build a modified filter pipe as

```
export function ignoreUnChanged<T>(source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
  return source.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged((obj1, obj2) => JSON.stringify({ obj: obj1 }) === JSON.stringify({ obj: obj2 })
  ))
}
```

But Typescript gives error as

```
Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 
'OperatorFunction<T, T>'.
 Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
Type 'import("/home/*******/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<T>' is not assignable to type
```

Is there a way to efficienty solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you use the spread operator to change the object instance, you can use obj1 === obj2.  This may not work depending on your specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your use-case is very simple and you don't need to make `ignoreUnChanged` configurable you can use just the following:

```
const ignoreUnChangedSimple = distinctUntilChanged((obj1, obj2) => JSON.stringify({ obj: obj1 }) === JSON.stringify({ obj: obj2 }));

...

source$
  .pipe(
    ignoreUnChangedSimple,
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

There're a couple of more complicated variants where the most complex (but also flexible) is like this:

```
export function ignoreUnChanged3<T>(someParams: any): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => source.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged((obj1, obj2) =>
      JSON.stringify({ obj: obj1 }) === JSON.stringify({ obj: obj2 })
    ),
  );
}
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-teaakn

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone else has a better answer on an efficient way to do deep object comparison. The lodash operator [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) has worked well for me in the past, but that's the extent of my experience.

What I can help with is the custom RxJS operator. This [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6R_1QB8q4o) by Ben Lesh and Tracy Lee at ng-conf 2019 is very, very good, and is the basis for all custom operators I've made.

What is missing in your code is you need to return a new Observable. Observables pipes are pure. So you need something like:

```
export function ignoreUnChanged<T>() {
return (source: Observable<T>) =>
    new Observable<T>(subscriber => {
        return source
            .pipe(
                distinctUntilChanged((obj1, obj2) => JSON.stringify({ obj: obj1 }) === JSON.stringify({ obj: obj2 })
            )
            .subscribe({
                next: v => subscriber.next(v),
                error: e => subscriber.error(e),
                complete: () => subscriber.complete()
            });
    });
}
```

And that would work something like:

```
this.stateObject$.pipe(ignoreUnChanged()).subscribe(obj => heavyComputeTask(obj))
```

I hope that helps. Best of luck.

Comment: .subscribe create more memory problems, than it solves. Also mono type Error still persists. @martin's Answer with your lodash suggestion makes a lot of sense